# How to copy the same file with different name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to copy a same file into 100 times with series of number.

Example: If file name is appple1 means I want in apple1, apple2, apple3, etc..

Comment: Do you have any question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from shutil import copyfile

for i in range(2, 100+1):
    src = 'apple1'
    dst = 'apple%i' % i
    copyfile(src, dst)
```

The reason you do `100+1` is that `range(2, 100)` will return values `[2, 3, 4... 98, 99]` (in mathematics this is called a half-open interval, since the 2 is included, but the 100 is not).